# Chart.js - How to set animation speed?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js ([documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)), but there doesn't seem to be an option to set the **animation speed**.

I can't even seem to find an animation speed / time variable in the source code.

How do I go about doing this?

(ps: I'm using Doughnut charts)

**EDIT**: Changing `animationSteps`, shows weird artefacts after the animation is complete, for several values (ie: 30 or 75). 60 is working fine. And it doesn't only appear with 100+ values of the chart:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the animationSteps?

Comment: @VoronoiPotato That seems to work for the speed.. Although with certain values (ie: 30 or 75), after the animation completes some weird artefacts appear (see my edit).

Answer (score 8):

I love Chart.js, but this is definitely a part of the API that could stand to be improved for the sake of clarity.

Chart.js uses the [window.requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method for animations, which is a more modern and efficient way to animate in the browser, since it only redraws on each screen refresh (i.e., based on the screen refresh rate, usually 60Hz). That prevents a lot of unnecessary calculations for frames that will never actually render.

At 60 frames/second, one frame lasts 16-2/3 milliseconds (1000ms / 60). Chart.js appears to [round this off to 17ms](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/src/Chart.Core.js#L2087), though. The API allows you to specify the number of steps [globally](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration), e.g.:

```
Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 60;
```

or [just for the donut chart](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-chart-options):

```
new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, {
  animationSteps: 60
});
```

Multiply 60 steps by 17ms/frame and your animation will run 1020ms, or just over one second. Since JavaScript programmers are used to thinking in milliseconds (not frames at 60Hz), to convert the other way, just divide by 17 to get the number of steps, e.g.:

```
Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = Math.round(5000 / 17); // results in 294 steps for a 5-second animation
```

Hope that helps. I'm not sure what would cause those weird artifacts, though.

Comment: This does not seem to have an effect anymore. Solution by rcbjmbadb using `animation: {duration: 2000,},` works though.

Answer (score 4):

Use the animation object

```
options: {
        animation: {
            duration: 2000,
        },
```

I haven't see this documented anywhere, but it's incredibly helpful to not have to set the speed globally for every chart.

[I also answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567002/set-animation-speed-chartjs)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this question in the future (like I did), there is a new way of changing the animation duration. I guess this was an update to the Chart.js library at some point :-)

`Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = [ms];`

So, for example, if you want a very fast 200ms animation, you can:

`Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 200;`

Hope this helps someone :-)