# Set Animation speed - ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, chart.js

I am trying to set the animation speed of a pie chart in chartJS.

I've tried the following:

1. numSteps: Number
2. animationSteps: Number
3. Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = Number

None of these have changed the speed. Any advice?

```
 var myNewChart;
    var data = [
        {
        value: 30,
        label: "hello",
        color: "#F7464A"
      }, {
        value: 50,
        color: "#E2EAE9"
      }, {
        value: 100,
        color: "#D4CCC5"
      }, {
        value: 40,
        color: "#949FB1"
      }, {
        value: 100,
        color: "#4D5360"
      },
    
    ];
    
    
    var options = {
      animation: true,
      animationEasing: 'easeInOutQuart',
      animationSteps: 80,
      multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"
    
    };
    
    
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart")
                                        .getContext("2d");
    
    myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, options);
```

Comment: hi, did you tried Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 3000; ?

Comment: Wow. that worked perfectly! Thank you!!

Comment: won't this change animation durations for all the charts in the page ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 3000;`

Answer (score 11):

Use the animation object

```
options: {
        animation: {
            duration: 2000,
        },
        ...
}
```

I haven't see this documented anywhere, but it's incredibly helpful to not have to set the speed globally for every chart.

Comment: hey. when i add this to my Bar options, it doesn't even load the Bar graph.

Comment: @momal can you show me where you're adding it?  I've never had an issue