# How to set ChartJS animation speed?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I understand that I need to set `Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = some value`. I just don't know where I place this line. I've previously declared it everywhere and it doesn't seem to change anything. I thought that I could set it globally after importing Chart.

Here's the Chart Component.

```
<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js'
import config from '../config.js'

Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 3000

export default {
  name: 'Chart',
  props: ["positions"],
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.loadData()
    this.createChart('canvas', config)
  },
  methods: {
    loadData() {
      this.positions.forEach((position) => {
        config.data.labels.push(position.symbol)
        config.data.datasets[0].data.push(position.closePrice)
      })
    },
      createChart(id, data) {
        const ctx = document.getElementById(id)
        new Chart(ctx, {
          type: data.type,
          data: data.data,
          options: data.options,
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The chart's configuration.

```
const config = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: '',
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#48beff',
          '#3dfaff',
          '#43c59e',
          '#3d7068',
          '#14453d',
      ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
  },
}

export default config
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chart.js - How to set animation speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837523/chart-js-how-to-set-animation-speed)

Comment: @ÁlvaroTihanyi I think it should, but the speed doesn't change no matter where I place `Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = some value` within my provided code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The problem was that the closing `<style/>` tag in my Component was missing. The styles were applied once it was added, and setting `Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration` now works as expected.